# How do you make two UI-differing products from one codebase?

Tags: c#, configuration, product

We have a C# product developed under two names with two different logos (and some other strings) and we need a way of choosing/displaying these different values, depending on how the app is configured (at either compile time or runtime, no preference yet).

The business logic, UI layout etc will be the same for both versions.

The current code is somewhat legacy, so we have a lot of strings scattered throughout business logic etc. We don't really use resource files or anything like that. Internationalisation isn't an immediate problem, but may be in the near future.

I was considering the following approaches:

1. A run time dictionary, populated with a compile-time script, or as a facade to an XML dictionary (or similar), with a similar construct for images, using enums or some other internal value as a key.
2. Using Microsoft Resource files (.resx), but from what I've seen, these seem to be intended for different languages (french etc), rather than different product configurations
3. Different build Visual Studio projects, storing the strings in some way in separate projects (so that the build project references the business logic + product_version_X_strings projects)
4. Some permutation of 1 - 3

It has also been suggested that we run the two product versions in different git branches, and search and replace the relevant strings.

Ideally the solution could be extended/expanded to include (and hence centralise) all user-facing strings contained in the application.

Is there a better way to do this, or some construct I'm not aware of? What's the preferred approach?

Comment: if the code base is the same and it's really just the branding that's different, why not tokenize your configuration and have specific product installer for each product that replaces the configuration tokens with the specific values, image paths, etc?  The one catch though maybe "branding" the dlls if they need specific copyright, product name etc.

Comment: @StinkyTowel I was kind of thinking along those lines in the third option, when it comes to deployment. Branding the dlls isn't necessary, just the average joe UI level (i.e. within the app, and the main install directory). It's the next step beyond that, I'm not sure of, i.e. how to package the strings.

Comment: Are you using TFS to build?

Comment: Nope. nmake for releases (makefile does stuff like generate manual tests, copy to sales server etc) and the plain built in build with VS.